# WT901BLE not showing/advertising service UUID to the ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, bluetooth-low-energy, iot, uuids

We are pairing WT901BLE device with the ESP32.When WT901BLE is paired with smart phone application Reconnect then service UUID is shown. I have read on some forums that some devices don't advertise service UUID and ESP32 only analyzes advertised data so that's why ESP32 can't see the service UUID of WT901BLE.Someone proposed on git to a similar issue that library code need to be updated for ESP32 to read scan response for data other than advertised data also then it will work. Can someone tell whether this is the only solution or there is some better way to do it. Secondly, which library need to be updated to get the desired result?

Comment: Ah, it's Friday.  From their site: "BUY WITH *CONFIRDENCE*".  Hmmm, that effort on their part doesn't really help the situation...  They also say: 
Q: Is the sensor compatible with MCU like Arduino?
A: The sensor is Bluetooth 5.0 communication, built-in nRF52832 chip.
... it is required to build a same nRF52832 chip on Arduino board as a master.
And the sensor can work as slave. ... It is recommended that you can study the sensor's communication protocol for research and development.
Please be noted that the service related to the sensor's integration is not supported.

Comment: This is purely about programming, usage or so, not an EE question, IMHO.